# Not able to build Maven project with Java 1.7

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a maven project that is in Java 1.7 but getting the below issue

```
[INFO] Downloading from : ``https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.604 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-26T12:38:34+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (``https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2``): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I tried multiple solutions that are present on internet but nothing seems to be working

Comment: It says there is no connection to `repo.maven.apache.org`. Check your network connection as it has nothing to do with your jdk version

Comment: I did, but the wonder here is it is able to build with jdk 1.8

Comment: It could be an SSL/TLS compatibility issue

Comment: The issue is this: `Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org ` ... Furthermore I strongly recommend to use a more recent JDK like 11 and use the `--release` option to build Java 7 compatible class files etc.

Comment: Thank you all of you for suggesting solutions . the problem was with the setting.xml location.
I was on my company VPN and configured proxy in settings.xml in C:/users/userName/.m2 folder to allow maven to download jars, but It was still failing . The problem was with the location of .m2 folder.

I used goal value while builing project as 'clean install -X' which provided me from where it is actually referring that xml.
**[DEBUG] Reading global settings from settings.xml** and then I updated settings.xml there and able to build project successfully.

Comment: Great to hear that now it's working...